# Appx1101 while referring multi targeted project

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, multitargeting

I have project that referring .net starndard 2.0 and .net version 4.6.1. When I make a project reference with the UWP App I am facing the issue APPX1101: payload contains two or more files with same destnation path. Is it possible to refer the multi targeted project to the UWP application?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your project structure? A UWP app can't reference .NET 4.6.1

Comment: I have an UWP project with min and max targeted version as 16299. I have a .Net standard library which has multiple targets .net standard 2.0 and .net 4.6.1. When I make it as a project reference it got referenced and it does not shows any error when i build it from Visual studio 2017 version 15.5.7. When I build the solution through script It showing the error as APPX1101: Payload containstwo or more files with same destination path.

Comment: Where does .NET 4.6.1 come into it?

Comment: I have manually edit the csproj file of the .Net standard library. In my solution I have used the wpf application. So i need this target to be added.

Comment: You can't add 4.6.1 dependencies and still claim to have a Standard 2.0 project. What do you need 4.6.1 for?